# SignalR client call

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have the following line of code in a signalR application client that receives a url message received from another client within the application.

```
serverHub.On("flush", message => System.Console.WriteLine(message));
```

I now want to assign the message to a string but I cannot just do this

```
 string qs = serverHub.On("flush", message => System.Console.WriteLine(message)).ToString();
```

However I get this output SignalR.Client.Infrastructure.DisposableAction instead of a text message, could someone tell me why this is the case, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that?

```
string qs;
serverHub.On("flush", message => {
    qs = message;
    System.Console.WriteLine(message);
});
```